# SQL query for finding positions in string

Tags: sql, string, position

need help on sql query to find the positions. for example if I have a string "111444411114444411111"
i need the positions of 4 for example for the above string i need the postions of 4 from to :as 
 4 to 7, 
12 to 16

Comment: you want to do this is in SQL?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(MAX)='111444411114444411111'

;WITH T AS(
    SELECT LEFT(@var, 1) Cha, 1 pos, 1 Ind
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@var, Ind+1, 1), 
        CASE WHEN Cha=SUBSTRING(@var, Ind+1, 1) THEN pos ELSE pos+1 END,
        Ind+1 
    FROM T
    WHERE Ind+1<=LEN(@var)
)
SELECT CAST(MIN(Ind) AS NVARCHAR)+' to '+CAST(MAX(Ind) AS NVARCHAR) Positions
FROM T WHERE Cha='4' 
GROUP BY pos
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [CHARINDEX](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEIQFjAD&url=http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=4a59645b-a5a1-4099-b6d2-959d8644cbed&tkw=uses-of-the-charindex-function&ei=lxnqUtexEsixrgeWtYHADQ&usg=AFQjCNGzpFcFNrzuKoC1R_ghwZgx7yTSBg&bvm=bv.60444564,d.bmk) to find the postion of the character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

See also: [MSDN - SQL Server - CHARINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
declare @str varchar(200);
set @str = '111444411114444411111'
declare @ind int;
set @ind = 1;
declare @len int;
set @len = len(@str);


while (@ind <= @len and @ind >= 1)
begin
    set @ind = charindex('4', @str, @ind);
    if (@ind <= 0) break;
    print @ind;
    set @ind = @ind + 1;
end
```